# Text Area turning to div when clicked outside

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, rich-text-editor, use-ref

I am trying to create a text area with react and tailwind which I can enter text in and when I click outside of the text area it turns into a regular div displaying the text previously entered in the text area. I am working towards replacing the text area with an editor as the next step so that when I click inside the editor I can edit text and when I click outside the text shows as a div. Can someone help me?

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";


function DraftPage(props) {
   const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false)
   let text = "fff";
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isSelected)
            document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutside, true)
        else
            document.addEventListener('click', handleClickOutsideActive, true)

    },[])

    const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
        if (refOne.current!= null)
            if (refOne.current.contains(e.target)) {
                console.log("clicked inside...")
                text = e.target.value;
                setIsSelected(true);

                }
    }

    const handleClickOutsideActive = (e) => {
            if (refTwo.current!=null )
                if (isSelected && !refTwo.current.contains(e.target)) {
                    console.log("clicked outside...")
                    setIsSelected(false);
                    }
        }




    const refOne = useRef(null);
    const refTwo = useRef(null);
    const res1 = <div ref={refTwo}><textArea  placeholder={text} class="w-[750px] h-[200px] border
    border-4 border-red-400 m-10 bg-gray-100"></textArea></div>
    const res2 = <div ref={refOne}  class="w-[750px] h-[200px] border border-4 border-green-700
    bg-green-300 m-10">{text}</div>

  return <div>{isSelected ? res1 : res2}</div>
}


export default DraftPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `useRef` and outside click handlers. You can handle the `onBlur` event of the `textarea` for not selected cases, and the `onClick` event of the `div` for the selected cases.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function DraftPage(props) {
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState("fff");

  const res1 = (
    <div>
      <textarea
        onBlur={() => setIsSelected(false)}
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
        className="w-[750px] h-[200px] border
    border-4 border-red-400 m-10 bg-gray-100"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
  const res2 = (
    <div
      style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}
      onClick={() => setIsSelected(true)}
      className="w-[750px] h-[200px] border border-4 border-green-700
    bg-green-300 m-10"
    >
      {text}
    </div>
  );

  return <div>{isSelected ? res1 : res2}</div>;
}

export default DraftPage;
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/text-area-and-div-g7fhct) for a live working example of this code.